# install different version python

Tags: python, python3, pip

i'm using the iso file built on arm for mac m1 **jammy-desktop-arm64.iso** my default version of python is **3.10.12**  and i run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppac
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8

nano ~/.bashrc
```

insert in the bash

```
alias python=‘/usr/bin/python3.8’
```

but when i try

```
python -V
```

it's says me

```
bash: '/usr/bin/python3.8' : File or directory does not exist
```

how can i run another version of python

Answer (score 1):

Generally, installing a different version of Python in `/usr/bin` is a bad idea, as your system can get confused by invoking the wrong Python version. The proper way to do this is to use `pyenv` (https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) or something similar to isolate the Python version you want to the application you want to use it for, rather than impose a different version of Python on the whole system.

It is likely that this package (for this reason) installed itself elsewhere. To find where it might be, use

```
dpkg --search bin/python3.8
```

You may find that it's in `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`, which would be a safer place to put it.

The other possibility is that you may have the wrong package. On my system (22.04), the `python3` executable is in a package called `python3.10-minimal`; the package `python3` has no executable. I can't access your repo so I can't confirm.